# graphing an equation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a function that will graph whatever formula I tell it to.

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
def graph(formula, x_range):  
    x = np.array(x_range)  
    y = formula  
    plt.plot(x, y)  
    plt.show()
```

When I try to call it the following error happens, I believe it's trying to do the multiplication before it gets to `y = formula`.

```
graph(x**3+2*x-4, range(-10, 11))

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>  
    graph(x**3+2*x-4, range(-10, 11))  
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is because in line

```
graph(x**3+2*x-4, range(-10, 11))
```

x is not defined.

The easiest way is to pass the function you want to plot as a string and use `eval` to evaluate it as an expression.

So your code with minimal modifications will be

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
def graph(formula, x_range):  
    x = np.array(x_range)  
    y = eval(formula)
    plt.plot(x, y)  
    plt.show()
```

and you can call it as

```
graph('x**3+2*x-4', range(-10, 11))
```

Comment: there's no need at all to use eval here, and it adds overhead

Comment: thank you that worked perfectly. thought that might be the case but had no idea how to un-string it

Comment: [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/7758804)

Answer (score 81):

Your guess is right: the code is trying to evaluate `x**3+2*x-4` immediately.  Unfortunately you can't really prevent it from doing so.  The good news is that in Python, functions are first-class objects, by which I mean that you can treat them like any other variable.  So to fix your function, we could do:

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

def graph(formula, x_range):  
    x = np.array(x_range)  
    y = formula(x)  # <- note now we're calling the function 'formula' with x
    plt.plot(x, y)  
    plt.show()  

def my_formula(x):
    return x**3+2*x-4

graph(my_formula, range(-10, 11))
```

[image]

If you wanted to do it all in one line, you could use what's called a `lambda` function, which is just a short function without a name where you don't use `def` or `return`:

```
graph(lambda x: x**3+2*x-4, range(-10, 11))
```

And instead of `range`, you can look at `np.arange` (which allows for non-integer increments), and `np.linspace`, which allows you to specify the start, stop, and the number of points to use.

Comment: Is there any way to out put the interactive graph in .html, like though jupyter notebook, I want to make a .html file that people can play with.

Comment: This is  7 years later, but I do hope you can answer. Inside the "graph" function, when you type "y = formula(x)", how does this work exactly? Inside the function, the formula (is it an object?) is the same with the my_formula because that is the "value" we give to graph's argument "formula"? Thanks..

Comment: @thenac - You have probably figured it out by yourself already, however it is exactly like you said. That would work with any function you would define and would match it: say my_formula(x) would be defined as cos(x) then when calling graph(my_formula, ...) would indeed produce the graph of a cos(x) formula under the range specifics you have defined. I hope this addresses your request.

Answer (score 10):

To plot an equation that is not solved for a specific variable (like circle or hyperbola):

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
plt.figure() # Create a new figure window
xlist = np.linspace(-2.0, 2.0, 100) # Create 1-D arrays for x,y dimensions
ylist = np.linspace(-2.0, 2.0, 100) 
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist) # Create 2-D grid xlist,ylist values
F = X**2 + Y**2 - 1  #  'Circle Equation
plt.contour(X, Y, F, [0], colors = 'k', linestyles = 'solid')
plt.show()
```

More about it: http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.867/wiki/images/3/3f/Plot-python.pdf