# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x, function

I'm trying to define a heaviside function in python but am getting a weird error. I'm not sure what 'type' refers to because 0 can be nothing but an integer. Please advise

```
#Part A - Plot function against values of variable x
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as quad
import math 

#make heaviside "theta" function

x = int 
def heaviside (x): 
    if (x >= 0):
        return 1
    else: 
    return 0 

#plot
x = int
y = heaviside(x)*[1-heaviside(x-1)]
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: ```x = int``` What should this do?` How much python experience do you have?

Comment: Did you read the error message? You're setting `x` to `int`, which is a `type`, and comparing it to `0`, which is an `int`.

Comment: I think op is trying to simply use y as a function to calculate the `y`s for their graph. afaik you need to give `pyplot.plot` a sequence of y values, there's no way to give just a formula

Comment: @RyanHaining Maybe, but this does not matter much. Even in the most exotic functional-programming settings, this code can't work as there are no constants limiting something at all (infinite plot?).

Comment: @sascha if op can answer the question * in `heaviside(x-1)` what do you expect `x-1` to be?* with a value, then it must be something else. What I'm assuming op is trying to say here is that x is some int value, and y is calculated based on that x. Confirming that would lead to an actual solution for what op is trying to solve. The `y = ` line would make sense with a lambda (though not supported by matplotlib) as in `y = lambda x: heaviside(x)*[1-heaviside(x-1)]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [graphing an equation with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000595/graphing-an-equation-with-matplotlib) the second answer there seems best

Answer (score 1):

When you declare x=int you are equating x to the datatype int, not to an instance of that datatype. 
You can run something like this code to see it.

```
>>> x = int
>>> x(4.5)
4
```

is equivalent to running

```
>>>int(4.5)
4
```

If you pass a numeric value for x instead, like x=4 then you won't have this error.

The code below doesn't raise this error anymore. The resulting plot doesn't show much; but there is no TypeError: unorderable types: type() >= int()

```
#Part A - Plot function against values of variable x
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as quad
import math 

#make heaviside "theta" function


def heaviside (x): 
    if (x >= 0):
        return 1
    else: 
        return 0 

#plot
x = 5
y = heaviside(x)*[1-heaviside(x-1)]
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: I never saw this kind of example after many years of python (probably because i never needed it). Nice (although it's probably on some higher level than the question asks for)!

Comment: okay, i tried setting x equal to a real integer value and get the same error. i also tried not defining x at all and still get the same error

Comment: @atemptcode Your problem is the definition of y. Read the duplicate-link and maybe some numpy/matplotlib tutorials.

Comment: @pabtorre ah okay I better understand the way matlab takes inputs. would i be able to use np.linspace to assign x to more values?

Comment: @sascha will do

Answer (score 0):

You are setting x incorrectly.  If you want x to be an integer, simply use the assignment operator like below.

```
x = 5
```

Comment: wouldn't setting x to a specific integer defeat the point of defining a function wherein x takes on any value?

Comment: @atemptcode you misunderstand matplotlib, you need to give it a sequence of y values to graph, not a formula